# spicy.signal.detrend not plotting as expected

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, python-xarray

I am attempting to detrend 3D gridded data using spicy.signal.detrend(), https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.detrend.html, and then turning it into an Xarray DataArray in order to use for correlations. Although, whenever I plot the detrended data, I end up with an inconsistency along the Prime Meridian, as seen below. I tried to add a cyclic point, hoping that it might fix the discrepancy, but had no luck. I am not completely set on using this function, so if anyone else has another option of how to do this, I would greatly appreciate just as much! The images below show the raw data on the left and the detrended data from spicy.signal.detrend() on the right. Thank you!

```
    sst_1 = xr.DataArray(data = signal.detrend(sst_cam1.ts)).rename({'dim_0': 'year','dim_1': 'lat', 'dim_2' : 'lon'}).assign_coords(year = time_his)
```

[[image: 1]

Comment: the default axis is -1 (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.detrend.html#scipy-signal-detrend). If your time axis is the first, then try setting it to 0: `axis=0`

Comment: Great! This seems to have worked perfectly! Thank you for your help and feedback. :)